# network to OSX from ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, samba

When I try to connect to my OSX machine from ubuntu like `smb://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/` 
I get a prompt for username and password that I fill out and confirmed the credentials are correct from my OSX machine.

[image]

But I cannot connect, I dont get any warnings just a quick refresh of that prompt and nothing.

From OSX i have tried this `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server SigningRequired false`

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7589427?start=0&tstart=0

I have confirmed file sharing is on and users have read & write privilege.

What am I overlooking?

log output

```
Nov 16 18:24:14 myUser org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1806]: Kinit for macUser to access (null) failed: Cannot determine realm for host
Nov 16 18:24:14 myUser org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1806]: NTLMSSP packet check failed due to short signature (0 bytes)!
Nov 16 18:24:14 myUser org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1806]: NTLMSSP NTLM2 packet check failed due to invalid signature!
```